# Is there a Flex equivalent of GWT-RPC?

Tags: apache-flex, gwt, gwt-rpc

Right now a lot of my applications use GWT-RPC for retrieving POJO's from a GWT RemoteService which in turn calls a Web Service (SOAP) to get the data. I am evaluating Flex  and didn't really see anything truly analogous to this simple architecture. Anything I may have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMF is Adobe's compact binary message format for use in Flash / Flex applications.  BlazeDS is the open source reference implementation for Java, using essentially nothing more than a simple "message broker" servlet to handle requests. This is similar to how services are exposed in GWT, although Blaze uses a single servlet, not multiple as in GWT.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf

Comment: Cool Blaze looks pretty close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Anyone know the efficiency in terms of size of data transfer of AMF vs GWT-RPC?

Answer (score 1):

[BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/), particularly with [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex).

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/java_flex.html) help you? I'm not too familiar with GWT-RPC, but is the AMF protocol what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, AMF looks like the way we will end up going.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the main choice here is BlazeDS, which is Adobe's open-sores server product for exposing flex-native server RPC and messaging. BlazeDS on its own is a bit clunky, and if you use Spring on the server, there is a slick integration available between Spring and Blaze.

Another, 3rd-party alternative is GraniteDS, which does much the same thing as Blaze, but is Spring-friendly out of the box, and does quite a lot more than Blaze (e.g. runtime compilation and generation of SWF files from the webapp). I haven't tried Granite, but it looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks I may check out Granite as well.